# When pressing Up+left + another key, the last key doesn't 'work'

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, input-device

I hope I'm right in thinking this is the site where you post general computer-related problems...

A problem I have when playing games (since you won't be pressing multiple keys simultaneously anytime else), is that when I press up/left and then another key, it fails to 'register' as if that last key is never pressed. This doesn't happen when I'm pressing any other two arrow keys, e.g. down/left or up/right.
The weird thing is that when I'm playing with WASD instead of the arrow keys, i still have this problem! Meaning W+A+another button doesn't work.

If anyone knows what I should, I'd appreciate the help. (My reflexes are fast and I can always circumvent this problem, but it's quite annoying and shouldn't exist to begin with!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/385338/keyboard-selective-ghosting

You might also want to see http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx for more info

Answer (score 0):

One of the  first hits from google with a cursory search takes me to stack exchange where this question has already been answered:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses

TL;DR: its your keyboard that is causing the limit - you will have to buy a better one...